# Applying a custom function to pandas Series produces AttributeError

Tags: python, pandas, apply, attributeerror

I want to create a custom summary function for pandas Series.

```
df["tmk"].min()
df["tmk"].max()
```

this works.

```
def min_max(x):
    minimum = x.min()
    maximum = x.max()
    print(f'Min: {minimum} | Max: {maximum}')

df["tmk"].apply(lambda x: min_max(x))

AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'min'
```

I guess I am doing a mistake here. Can anyone help me with how to apply the function correctly?

Comment: Try `min_max(df["tmk"])`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If use [`Series.apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.apply.html) it loop by each value of column. Error means there is no `min` and `max` for scalars.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
         'tmk':[4,5,4,5,5,np.nan],
})


def min_max(x):
    minimum = x.min()
    maximum = x.max()
    print(f'Min: {minimum} | Max: {maximum}')
```

You need processing all values of column by [`Series.pipe`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.pipe.html):

```
df["tmk"].pipe(min_max)
```

Or pass Series to function like mentioned @AkshayNevrekar in comments:

```
min_max(df["tmk"])
```

Another idea is use [`DataFrame.apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) - added `[]` for one column `DataFrame`:

```
df[["tmk"]].apply(min_max)

Min: 4.0 | Max: 5.0
```

---

Another method is use [`Series.describe`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.describe.html) or [`Series.agg`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.agg.html):

```
print (df['tmk'].describe())

count    5.000000
mean     4.600000
std      0.547723
min      4.000000
25%      4.000000
50%      5.000000
75%      5.000000
max      5.000000
Name: tmk, dtype: float64

print (df['tmk'].agg(['min', 'max']))
min    4.0
max    5.0
Name: tmk, dtype: float64
```

Also is possible add `format` like mentioned @Jon Clements, thank you:

```
print ('Min: {min} | Max: {max}'.format_map(df['tmk'].agg(['min', 'max'])))

Min: 4.0 | Max: 5.0
```

Comment: Although given the use case - something like: `'Min: {min} | Max: {max}'.format_map(df['tmk'].agg(['min', 'max']))` would be fine here...

Comment: Thank you, this is my favorite solution since it allows me to do this:

```columns = ["tmk", "tgk", "tnk", "txk"]
for column in columns:
    wetterdaten_level1[column].pipe(min_max)```

Answer (score 1):

For such kind of analysis just use [describe](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.describe.html) method of series.

If you want some exlanation of your mistake here it is. Doing this:

```
df["tmk"].apply(lambda x: min_max(x))
```

you are applying your function to **every value** in your series. That value has type 'float'. Floats in python doesn't have method max or min. Instead you can use:

```
df["tml"].min()
```

or maybe built-in python min/max like:

```
min(df["tml"])
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to get Min and Max, it may be easier for you to use the `describe()` method

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# fix seeds so we get the same numbers
np.random.seed(42)
a = np.random.normal(0, 1, 10)
np.random.seed(42)
b = np.random.uniform(0, 1, 10)

df = pd.DataFrame({"A": a, "B": b})
df.describe()

>>>            A          B
count  10.000000  10.000000
mean    0.448061   0.520137
std     0.723008   0.315866
min    -0.469474   0.058084
25%    -0.210169   0.210649
50%     0.519637   0.599887
75%     0.737498   0.726014
max     1.579213   0.950714
```

You can get the min, max and other metrics from there